# Get artist name in Unicode with WMP SDK

Tags: com, windows-media-player

I am writing a plug-in for Windows Media Player and need to get the name of the artist of the song currently playing.

I use IWMPMedia->getItemInfo(L"Artist", &bstrArtist) to get the artist name. It works fine with ASCII names but if the name is Unicode, it returns a blank string.

Does anyone know how to get around that problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I was calling getItemInfo() too soon. Case closed.